# Pandas substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
     contract
 0   WTX1518X22
 1   WTX1518X20.5
 2   WTX1518X19
 3   WTX1518X15.5
```

I need to add a new column containing everything following the last 'X' from the first column. So the result would be:

```
     contract        result
 0   WTX1518X22      22
 1   WTX1518X20.5    20.5
 2   WTX1518X19      19
 3   WTX1518X15.5    15.5
```

So I figure I first need to find the string index position of the last 'X' (because there may be more than one 'X' in the string). Then get a substring containing everything following that index position for each row.

EDIT:

I have managed to get the index position of 'X' as required:

```
df.['index_pos'] = df['contract'].str.rfind('X', start=0, end=None)
```

But I still can't seem to get a new column containing all characters following the 'X'. I am trying:

```
df['index_pos'] = df['index_pos'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df['result'] = df['contract'].str[df['index_pos']:]
```

But this just gives me an empty column called 'result'. This is strange because if I do the following then it works correctly:

```
df['result'] = df['contract'].str[8:]
```

So I just need a way to not hardcode '8' but to instead use the column 'index_pos'. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't want to sound like a perl fanboy, but have you tried regex? Something simple like `df. contract.str.extract(".*X(.*)")` probably already works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use vectorised [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) to split the string and cast the last split to `float`:

```
In [10]:
df['result'] = df['contract'].str.split('X').str[-1].astype(float)
df
​
Out[10]:
       contract  result
0    WTX1518X22    22.0
1  WTX1518X20.5    20.5
2    WTX1518X19    19.0
3  WTX1518X15.5    15.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import re as re
df['result'] = df['contract'].map(lambda x:float(re.findall('([0-9\.]+)$',x)[0]))

Out[34]: 
       contract  result
0    WTX1518X22    22.0
1  WTX1518X20.5    20.5
2    WTX1518X19    19.0
3  WTX1518X15.5    15.5
```

A similar approach to the one by EdChump using regular expressions, this one only assumes that the number is at the end of the string.